# text selection disabled in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, text

When I'm trying to select text with the mouse on my website with internet explorer (I have v9 but, had same problem with v8), i just can't and can't figure out why

Normally with chrome or firefox, i have no problem to select text with the mouse (which becomes white with a blue background), click right to get the menu and then copy the text or whatever, but with ie, just nothing and no idea what kind of problem it is, html, css, javascript, other?

Does have anybody an idea how to fix this? I've aleardy search for similar problem but no answer.

Thanks all for answers

Comment: can you show live example.?

Comment: see your console...      SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference 
main_function.min.js, line 61 character 165

Comment: solve this error and then try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js affecting your code so solve this error.

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference main_function.min.js, line 61 character 165
```

Comment: as i can see, i've missed checking js for ie... :s

Comment: a=document.getElementById("stick")?"fixed"==document.getElementById("stick").style.position error occur here.. in html no div with id 'stick' so this error occur..put a div with id stick or remove this line form js file...